# jQuery click doesn't work on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Here is the jQuery code which works on Firefox and IE but not on Chrome.
I placed the alert() to debug and it doesnt works on chrome or safari. Any ideas?
The bxslider jquery works but not the $(".locationoption").click(function() .
Here is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".locationoption").click(function() {
        var datastring = "location="+$("#locationselection").val()+"&language="+"<?php echo $language; ?>";

        alert(datastring);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/ajaxlocationsearch.php",
            data: datastring,
            cache: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#hotelselection").html(data);
            }
        });
    });

  $('#leftsidebarbanners').bxSlider({
    controls:true,
    nextText:"  Next &#8594;",
    prevText:"&#x2190; Previous  |",
  });

});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your dev tools? Try putting alert("Hello") as the first thing in the click function.  If that works you know it's an issue with the string.

Comment: Can you include the relevant html?

Comment: Did you try `$(".locationoption").on('click', function()` already?

Comment: @Jurik - That is exactly equivalent to using `.click()` as shown in the question. @satafaka - in Chrome press F12 to open the dev tools and then click "Console" to see if any errors are reported.

Comment: No errors reported ... The website is this --> http://www.secureshop.gr/POOL/acrosshotels/website/ . Just change location from the left side bar, near the slider.

Comment: try delegeting like : $(document).on('click','.locationoption',function() ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should not use the clicking on an "option" element because it is not really a DOM element I guess. It's completely drawn by the browser and as you noticed it can act different depending on the browser.

But use the change event of the select: "#locationselection". And maybe use the following syntax to fill the data:

```
$("#locationselection").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/ajaxlocationsearch.php",
        data: {
            location: $(this).val(),
            language: "<?php echo $language; ?>"
        },
        cache: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#hotelselection").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the JQuery Delegate.
[Link to JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Had a problem with dynamicly loaded content on my site aswell and delegate worked perfectly for me.

```
$("id of class of outer element").delegate( "id/class/element of content that is to be clicked", "click", function() {
      //do your stuff
);
```